# Brouwer's theorem for other topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

The Brouwer fixedpoint theorem about disk on $\mathbb{R}^2$ yields similar theorem about square  on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm wondering if this theorem true for some gluings of square. It's easy to see that for torus it's wrong, but does it true for projective plane or Klein bottle?

Comment: What is a one dimensional square?

Comment: It works with any nonempty space homeomorphic to a compact convex subset of some Euclidean space.

Comment: See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property and its references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One says that a space $X$ has the [fixed-point property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property) if every map $f:X\to X$ has a fixed point. For example, Brouwer's says that the euclidean closed balls have the fixed-point property.

There are many other spaces which have this property;  any compact absolute neighborhood retract with trivial rational homology has it, for example, and this generalizes Brouwer's theorem in a natural direction. In fact, Borsuk conjectured looong ago that every compact contractible has the fixed-point property, but now we have counterexamples.

Very recently, Jonathan Barmak has [shown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1722) that every compact connected CW-complex is weakly homotopically equivalent to a space with the fixed-point property. This implies that there is an inmense supply of spaces with the FPP.